# No display upload file size > 2mb

Tags: php

I'd like to check the size of my upload input file but if my file is bigger 2 mb the variable return 0 bite, can you tell me why?

```
$size = $_FILES['foto1']['size'];
echo $size;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured `php.ini` file ?

Comment: Your hosting company has probably limited uploads to 2mb using upload_max_filesize. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize. You may be able to increase it if your host allows you to customize settings with a php.ini file. If not, contact your host for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the following in the 'php.ini' file

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Comment: +1 This will only will only work if the host allows overriding settings with a php.ini file though.